# Unknow error connecting from ArcCatalog to Oracle

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, oracle-spatial, arccatalog

Currently I am running ArcMap 10.6.1 and try to connect with an Oracle 19c database. Unfortunately I only see "Unknown Error":

```
Underlying DBMS error[Unknown errorNo extended error.]
```

[image: unknownerror]

Yet I think, there should be everything in place from a patch-level perspective:
[image: installed patches]

I am also able to connect with the database using sqlplus via cmd and a tnsping from cmd also works just fine on the relevant port.

Are there any suggestions where I could find a log and does anyone know about a fix of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out, that the registry was wrong as the Oracle client installation was crooked. So I uninstalled oracle client, removed ORACLE relevant lines from PATH environment variable, removed ORACLE entries in the registry and reinstalled the Oracle Client.

No further adjustments were made on my side after this and it was connecting without an issue.

Comment: Just had a similar error where the Oracle Client 19c could not be loaded in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.2, the deinstall and install with the same parameters solved the problem.